# Charging paused, battery temperature too low

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, battery, charging

I dropped my Samsung Galaxy S2 in water, and now when I plug it in I get a message that says:

> Charging paused, battery temperature too low

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: How long ago did you drop your phone in water? Hours, days, weeks? Was it clean water, dirty water or salt water? Are you sure that it is entirely dried out, and there aren't any droplets shorting anything out inside the phone? See these previous questions for more info on water damage: [Fixing water damage in phone](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9616/) and [http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24436/](My android device has been splashed/soaked by sea water)

Comment: @GAThrawn At least an hour ago and clean water.. i will take a look thanks :)

Comment: if you have a hairdryer, use it and blow it to your S2's backplate and battery removed back for at least 10mins so it's inside will heat up a bit and maybe evaporate some water that got in.